# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at _010_fla::MainTimeline/frame31()

Tags: actionscript-3, typeerror

> TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
>   at _010_fla::MainTimeline/frame31()
>   at flash.display::MovieClip/gotoAndStop()
>   at Function/()
>   at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>   at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>   at fl.controls::ComboBox/onListChange()
>   at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
>   at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
>   at fl.controls::SelectableList/handleCellRendererClick()

I've been stuck with such an error for 2 days now, and however I search on solving this from the number of previous questions asked about this error, I still can't seem to get it to work, mainly because I don't understand it at all.

this is my source code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/5z33kdh1ibvnmto/010%20-%20dropdown%20isi%20as.fla

thank

Comment: you dropbox link isn't working. Also, it'd be better to provide code (in text form) here itself. BTW, the call stack of exception means that there is some code on Frame31 of your main movie which listening to list change event from ComboBox. That code is accessing an object's property but the object is 'null' at the time.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you are writing code on frames rather than different class file.

In frame case sometimes the object or method are not ready to be used when you switch frames from gotoAndStop() or gotoAndPlay();

My suggestion is add .1sec delay(Timer Event) before using anyFunction or using any property or anyThing... and when the timer gives you callback ... do whatever you want.

Try this worth a shot... This will definately solve your problem if i am understanding it correctly.